# Xamarin Forms GDrive integration

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there any Sample or blogs available which talks about Xamarin.Forms & Google Drive integration? I have read google docs and i can understand there is no official support as of now. But any alternate approach or workaround is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned there is no official libraries available for Xamarin.Forms & Google drive, but you can access gdrive using .Net nugets with some more platform specific codes in xamarin.forms. I have written a blog about it read it [here](https://xamarindev.blog/). Hope that blogs helps !

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, The link looks promising will give it a try.